# shiny - automatically jump into new appended tab

Tags: r, shiny

I struggle to get my app to automatically jump to the new appended tab once its created after you clicked one of the markers.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(shinydashboard)


pts <- data.frame(
  id= letters[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )],
  x = rnorm(10, mean = -93.625), 
  y = rnorm(10, mean = 42.0285)
)


# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(

  tabsetPanel(id='my_tabsetPanel',
              tabPanel('Map1',
                       leafletOutput('map1')   
              )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$map1 <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      setView(-93.65, 42.0285, zoom = 6)
  })


  observe({

    input$my_tabsetPanel

    tab1 <- leafletProxy('map1', data = pts) %>%
      clearMarkers() %>% 
      addCircleMarkers(lng = ~x, lat = ~y, radius = 4, layerId = ~id)


  })


observeEvent(input$map1_marker_click, { 
  tab_title <- input$map1_marker_click[1]
  appendTab(inputId = "my_tabsetPanel",
            tabPanel(
              tab_title,
              fluidRow(

                box('test')
                )))

  updateTabsetPanel(session, "my_tabsetPanel", selected = tab_title)

})

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I want the app to automatically jump into the new tab but somehow I guess I don't use the `updateTabsetPanel` right

Credit for the example code which is partly stolen from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503672/render-leaflet-markers-across-tabs-on-shiny-startup)

Comment: sorry which new tab are you talking about? i see only one tab here.

Comment: new tabs pop up once you click the marker. clarified in the text

Comment: please check the answer. it takes you to the new tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the way your tab_id's where set. there must have been some clash.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(shinydashboard)

pts <- data.frame(
  id= letters[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )],
  x = rnorm(10, mean = -93.625), 
  y = rnorm(10, mean = 42.0285)
)


# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(

  tabsetPanel(id='my_tabsetPanel',
              tabPanel('Map1',
                       leafletOutput('map1')   
              )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$map1 <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      setView(-93.65, 42.0285, zoom = 6)
  })


  observe({

    input$my_tabsetPanel

    tab1 <- leafletProxy('map1', data = pts) %>%
      clearMarkers() %>% 
      addCircleMarkers(lng = ~x, lat = ~y, radius = 4, layerId = ~id)


  })


observeEvent(input$map1_marker_click, { 
  tab_title <- input$map1_marker_click[1]
  appendTab(inputId = "my_tabsetPanel",
            tabPanel(
              tab_title, #paste0("tab_",tab_title),
              value = paste0("tab_",tab_title),
              fluidRow(

                box('test')

                #tags$b("some text")
                )))

  updateTabsetPanel(session, "my_tabsetPanel", selected = paste0("tab_",tab_title)) 

})

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks, will accept but would also like to keep the actual id name without any extensions. Its strange that you have to "rename" it?

Comment: that's probably because of the value class with css values i guess

Comment: we can solve that with value, so done that please check